# An internal error occurred during: "Import projects into workspace". -1

Tags: intershop

While importing my Intershop 7.9 project into Intershop Studio (Version: 4.6.3) I get the error below. Any idea, what is wrong here?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2017-08-23 17:45:56.282
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Import projects into workspace.".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.segment(Path.java:1050)
    at com.intershop.studio.cartridge.generation.EnfinityProjectType.guessProjectType(EnfinityProjectType.java:51)
    at com.intershop.studio.cartridge.generation.CartridgeProjectEclipseConfigurator.getEnfinityProjectType(CartridgeProjectEclipseConfigurator.java:224)
    at com.intershop.studio.cartridge.generation.CartridgeProjectEclipseConfigurator.getVariables(CartridgeProjectEclipseConfigurator.java:255)
    at com.intershop.studio.cartridge.generation.CartridgeProjectEclipseConfigurator.configure(CartridgeProjectEclipseConfigurator.java:136)
    at com.intershop.studio.cartridge.generation.CartridgeProjectEclipseConfigurator.configure(CartridgeProjectEclipseConfigurator.java:116)
    at com.intershop.studio.cartridge.gradle.CartridgeGradleImportOperation.perform(CartridgeGradleImportOperation.java:230)
    at com.intershop.studio.cartridge.ui.wizard.CartridgeGradleProjectImportWizard$1.runInWorkspace(CartridgeGradleProjectImportWizard.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an error that might occur if your multiproject or component set is located directly in the root folder of your filesystem. Is that the case? Nevertheless, I'm going to file a bug entry and this problem will be fixed immediately.

See https://jira.intershop.de/browse/ISTUDIO-772

Comment: Awesome! That solved it. I moved my project folder into a subfolder and now it works. Thanks! Nils